# adding jquery ui icon to a submit button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, button

I have the following code for a submit button my page:
The html markup is:

```
<td align="Right"><input type="submit" value="Add Driver" ></td>
```

and the jquery is:

```
$( "input[type=submit]" ).button().click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});
```

How would I add a ui icon to the above, specifically the `ui-icon-circle-plus`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your HTML like this:

```
<button type="submit">
    Add Driver
</button>
```

And then update your script like this:

```
$('button[type=submit]').button({icons: {primary: 'ui-icon-circle-plus'}}).click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mh5Pu/

Comment: I don't see any icon on the fiddle. It just is a text button.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
$( "input[type=submit]" ).button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus"}})      .click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});
```

or you set it afterwards:

```
$( "input[type=submit]" ).button( "option", "icons", { primary: "ui-icon-circle-plus", secondary: "<your_second_icon>" } );
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kfubw/) is an working example.

Comment: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kfubw/

you also have an error in your HTML syntax: this is the correct HTML: <td align="Right"><input type="submit" value="Add Driver" /></td>

Answer (score 1):

Look at the examples on http://jqueryui.com/button/#icons (specifically the icons).

Instead of using a submit input, try using a button.

Here's a modified version of the icon only button with ui-icon-circle-plus:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only"     role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Button with icon only">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">Button with icon only</span>
</button>
```